# Outlook Show Email Images to User

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to send mails to some users which are basically built over images. How can I get those images to download by default in the users' (outlook) mailbox?

I did try encoding the image in base64 and sending it, not as a hosted image but embedded in email-html. But that too, did not work :( (I was SO sure that it would)

The client (organization) is well aware of this (that we'll be exchanging mails). Is there any setting that can be tweaked in the admin panel of MSExchange or o365 which can allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Users have to have that set in their preferences.  You cannot make it automatically do it as an email sender due to SPAM senders and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook allows adding hidden attachments, you may refer mention they in the message body (embedded images). In the message body you may see the following tags:

```
<img src="cid:some-image-cid" alt="img" />
```

The "cid:" prefix means that name refers to the attached image with the specified content ID.

```
   Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(
    @"E:\Pictures\image001.jpg", 
    OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
  string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";
  attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);
  String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>", imageCid);
```

Comment: I'm not sending the image as attachment. The whole content of mail is just 1 image.

Comment: I understood it correctly initially. Instead of sending a link to the image somewhere you may embed that image into the email itself. In that case, there is no need to download it.